# Application is consuming power in the background if I set listener for Firebase Realtime Database in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use Firebase Realtime Database in my android application. When I try to read from database overriding method `onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)`

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error)
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
    }
});
```

it is working nice, but in morning my device (with Android 7.0) give me warning that my app is consuming power in the background. I don't find in documentation how unset listener if activity is paused/destroyed.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to add the listener?

Comment: If you're application is executing code, whether in the foreground or the the background, you will always be consuming power.

Comment: I use standart code from hint: myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
    }
});

Comment: @WadeWilson:when I use Firebase Cloud Messaging I don't got same warning although FCM events are occurs with more frequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to stop this from happening, you need to remove the listener accordingly to the life-cycle of your activity. So, please use the following line of code:

```
databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

So, if you have added the listener in `onStart` you have to remove it in `onStop`. If you have added the listener in `onResume` you have to remove it in `onPause`. If you have added the listener in `onCreate` you have to remove it in `onDestroy`.

But remember `onDestroy` is not always called!

Here is a graphic representation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think that it is what I search, but I want to check that warning will not appear, I'll test for a day and if not, I accept your answer as right.